# unique values of custom object NSString property in nsarray

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, nsset

I have an array which stores custom objects. 
Objects are of type Venue which have a property defined as name(which contains the names of venue).

Now I want to filter out objects with unique names.

This is how I was trying to do.

```
NSSet *uniqueVenuesSet = [NSSet setWithArray:[venueArray valueForKey:@"name"]];
```

`NSMutableArray *uniqueVenues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[uniqueVenuesSet allObjects]]`;

I get this error when I run this.

```
    -[NSCFString name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x69a6190
2010-10-24 09:25:31.832 [75790:207]  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFString name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x69a6190'
```

Can anyone give me a pointer on how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

This is because there is at least one `NSString` object in `venueArray`.

Make sure that every element in your `venueArray` is of type `Venue`.